# Maven BUILD FAILURE in my pipeline- java application

Tags: maven, jenkins, groovy, devops, pipeline

I'm trying to build my java based application using maven in jenkins pipeline, But I'm getting an error. I also tired creating this manually in server still the build is failed. Can anyone help me to fix this error.
I have attached my pom.xml for your reference

[This is error message I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Zxbk.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.javaproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>database_service_project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2</version>
    <name>database_service_project</name>
    <description>Project for Spring Boot</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <jacoco.version>0.8.7</jacoco.version>
        <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
            <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
            <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
            <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
        
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId> 
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.7</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>jacoco-site</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-releases</id>
            <url>http://3.88.105.164:8081/repository/maven-releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>maven-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://3.88.105.164:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

maven is installed and configured in my pipeline.
I want maven to built my application

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking
a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: The error you get does not relate to Maven at all.

Comment: Hi, Can you help me to fix this error